# How to add a named UCI section via lua?

Tags: lua, openwrt

I can't create a named UCI section via lua.
The equivalent using the command line is

```
uci set uhttpd.test=uhttpd
uci commit
```

Which gives a config file like

```
config uhttpd 'test'
```

I can't reproduce the syntax of the command-line with *set* or *add*.
The C [source](https://github.com/jkjuopperi/uci/blob/master/lua/uci.c) seems to say there is away to pass type to *add*

```
local uci = require "uci"
uci.add("uhttpd", "test") -- adds anonymous section
uci.set("uhttpd", "test", "listen_http", "0.0.0.0:81") -- not added as named section missing
uci.commit("uhttpd")
```

Comment: share your Lua script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wiki:

```
Add new section "name" with type "type":
x:set("config", "name", "type")
-- real world example:
x:set("network", "wan6", "interface")
```

https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/uci